# Как перед вставкой проверить, есть ли уже запись с заданным значением?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть такая процедура:

```
Procedure INSERT(I_NAME, I_NUM) 
IS
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO Account(NAME, NUM)
VALUES(I_NAME, I_NUM)

END INSERT;
```

Хочу с помошью `MERGE` проверить, если в таблице нет записи со значением `I_NUM` в столбце `NUM`, тогда сделать `INSERT`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: `MERGE ON (NAME=I_NAME) WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT`. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: @Akina а как этот код MERGE ON (NAME=I_NAME) WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT поимет что именно в этой Table надо сделать Insert?

Comment: Это не код, а шаблон кода. Остальное мясо нарастите сами.

Comment: @Akina MERGE INTO ACCOUNT a
               USING(SELECT NAME FROM ACCOUNT ) a1
               ON (a.NAME = I_NAME) WHEN MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO 
можете проветь это?

Comment: *можете проветь это?* Проверяйте сами. [Вот тут](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> как это сделать?

Сделать надо следующее:

1. Посмотреть в документации гл. [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-PROCEDURE.html#GUID-771879D8-BBFD-4D87-8A6C-290102142DA3), [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F).
2. Создать минимальный, воспроизводимый пример, например, на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c5431b7ee41ceaf14e7e4bea01b8e27f).
3. Задать вопрос, указав в нём сообшение об ошибке, и **обязательно пояснить**, какие сложности возникли при устранении ошибки:

   > ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
4. Теперь вам охотно помогут с решением:

   ```
   create table account (num, name) as select 1, 'name 1' from dual
   /
   create or replace procedure insertIfNotExists (num int, name varchar2) is
   begin 
       merge into account t using (
           select num num, name name from dual) s on (s.num = t.num)
       when not matched then insert values (s.num, s.name);
       dbms_output.put_line ('merged '||sql%rowcount||' row(s)'); 
   end insertIfNotExists;
   /
   begin  
       insertIfNotExists (1, 'name 1');
       insertIfNotExists (2, 'name 2');
   end;
   /
   dbms_output:
   start merge ...
   merged 0 row(s)
   merged 1 row(s)

   select * from account
   /
          NUM NAME  
   ---------- ------
            1 name 1
            2 name 2
   ```

   На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b45c71506eeb93cc0786fde5d0b32650).
5. Если предложенное решение помогло - принять ответ, если нет - оставить комментарий.